# IndexError: too many indices when working with pandas data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

wrote a function that finds the peaks and troughs a signal and outputs to two ndarray objects from the numpy library called mintab and maxtab whose indices are timestamps and whose values are the value of the peak.

I want to plot this data as a scatter plot with the timestampes as the x axis and values of peaks as y so i wrote this:

```
xMax = maxtab[:,0]
yMax = maxtab[:,1]
xMin = mintab[:,0]
yMin = mintab[:,1]

mpl.rc('figure', figsize=(20, 2))                     # configure plot window size
plt.scatter(xMax, yMax, color='g', alpha=1)
plt.scatter(xMin, yMin, color= 'r', alpha = 1)
```

But i keep getting an error that says: `IndexError: too many indices` and points to the line `xMin = mintab[:,0]`

I don't understand why this is happening and i can't find anything on google about it.

Comment: Ok, now that you've specified that `xMin` is an `ndarray`, are you sure it actually has two dimensions? Because you'll get that error if you try to give two-dimensional indices to a 1d array.

Comment: ahh I think this is definitely the problem. Thanks! Now i just need to figure out how to set xMin and xMax as a list of the indices of mintab and maxtab. Google time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm suprised you're not getting an unhashable type error:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [2]: df[:, 0]
# TypeError: unhashable type
```

If you want to select the 0 column in this way you should use loc:

```
In [3]: df.loc[:, 0]
Out[3]:
0    1
1    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Or select the column directly:

```
In [4]: df[0]
Out[4]:
0    1
1    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

If you want to specify the 0th column (regardless of label) use iloc:

```
In [5]: df.iloc[:, 0]
Out[5]:
0    1
1    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was confused when i first wrote the post, the objects being returned are not pandas series, rather they are ndarrays from numpy library. Sorry for the inconvenience!